# Download a file from a dropbox / file sharing site in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to download a certain dropbox zipped file somewhere. Is there a way I can do this in JavaScript and how can it be done? What I want is I want to download this zipped file in dropbox, so when you set the link, you can see the download button from the dropbox page, right? I want JS to download that instead of the web page or the item itself.

I want this to be automatic, not having the javascript show me where to place the file, but rather place it entirely on a computer URL I want to put it to.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Stack overflow is not a place where people write your code, show us what you have tried and we will assist.

Comment: I am sorry but I am new to javascript and was asking for an easier way, rather than using libraries I see in the internet, which does not comply to what I was looking for. :(

Comment: It's understandable, but keep in mind that we do need a direction of your code

Comment: When you go to dropbox, there is a download button there that will tell the user to download the file...I was wondering if what javascript code is needed to download that automatically without clicking the button. :(

Answer (score 1):

> When you go to dropbox, there is a download button there that will tell the user to download the file...I was wondering if what javascript code is needed to download that automatically without clicking the button.

Not possible. If that were possible any site you visit could literally just put anything they want anywhere on your computer.

The only way to download a file is through the API that the browser provides you which should always show a file explorer window.